# 404 with serving static files in a custom nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

In my nginx configuration, I have the following:

```
location /admin/ {
  alias /usr/share/php/wtlib_4/apps/admin/;

  location ~* .*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php_admin;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf|zip|rar|air)$ {
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
  }
}


  location ~ ^/admin/modules/([^/]+)(.*\.(html|js|json|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf|zip|rar|air))$ {
    alias /usr/share/php/wtlib_4/modules/$1/admin/$2;
  }

  location ~ ^/admin/modules/([^/]+)(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @php_admin_modules;
  }

location @php_admin {
    if ($fastcgi_script_name ~ /admin(/.*\.php)$) {
        set $valid_fastcgi_script_name $1;
    }
    fastcgi_pass $byr_pass;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/php/wtlib_4/apps/admin$valid_fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location @php_admin_modules {
    if ($fastcgi_script_name ~ /admin/modules/([^/]+)(.*)$) {
        set $byr_module $1;
        set $byr_rest $2;
    }
    fastcgi_pass $byr_pass;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/php/wtlib_4/modules/$byr_module/admin$byr_rest;
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Following is the requested url which ends up with "404":

```
http://www.{domainname}.com/admin/modules/cms/styles/cms.css
```

Following is the error log:

```
[error] 19551#0: *28 open() "/usr/share/php/wtlib_4/apps/admin/modules/cms/styles/cms.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: {domainname}.com, request: "GET /admin/modules/cms/styles/cms.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.{domainname}.com"
```

Following urls works fine:

```
http://www.{domainname}.com/admin/modules/store/?a=manage
http://www.{domainname}.com/admin/modules/cms/?a=cms.load
```

Can anyone see what the problem could be? Thanks.

PS. I am trying to migrate existing sites from apache to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your request gets sent to PHP, I would assume that the following location block does not match your request, although that is your intention.

```
location ~ ^/admin/modules/([^/]+).*\.html|js|json|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf|zip|rar|air))$ {
```

From the [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead,
>   match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then
>   use location / to match anything else.

What is your intention with the `([^/]+)` part in that location block? I think you can achieve what you want by simply removing that part.

```
location ~ ^/admin/modules/.*\.html|js|json|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf|zip|rar|air))$ {
```

Comment: Please refer to "location @php_admin_modules" block and see the two sets. "/admin/modules/store" in this path "store" is the module name and i need to know this in order to appropriately rewrite. PS. I am trying to migrate my existing sites from apache to nginx.